# Separate numbers from Sentence

Tags: vb.net

how to separate number from sentence like this?

```
Z        90.00000
```

or

```
              47540.00000
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use something like the regex below:

```
Dim regex As Regex = New Regex("\d+\.\d+")
Dim match As Match = regex.Match("Z        90.00000")
If match.Success Then
    Console.WriteLine(match.Value)
```

Here's a site with great RegEx tutorials and reference material:

http://www.regular-expressions.info/dotnet.html

Comment: is `Regex` has `Fix` or `Round` for numbers?

Comment: Well, you can put the regex match into a decmial.parse, then do a decimal.round.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0y1z063b